# Word meaning 'someone who has received a lot'

Tags: single-word-requests

What's a generic word for someone who has been given a lot [of good things]?

We were playing a party game last night wherein we were to describe our life in one word.  Later, as we drove home, my wife said the idea she wanted to get across was that she received a lot in different areas of her life, but that the word 'blessed' wasn't quite the right word.  Blessed has too much connotation of set apart or special.  Is there a word for a person that has been given many good things without being especially deserving or noteworthy as an individual?

(Note: I do think she is special and wonderful, but that doesn't help us think of a word that fit the description)

Comment: "Lucky" doesn't sound fancy but does the job.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about favoured (or favored if you're American)? To me that implies that you've received a lot, without specifying money, and also without implying either way whether you're deserving or not.

Answer (score 8):

I like "fortunate". Do you remember the great song "Fortunate son" by Creedence Clearwater Revival?:

> Some folks are born silver spoon in hand
>
> Lord, don't they help themselves, oh
>
> But when the taxman comes to the door
>
> Lord, the house looks like a rummage sale, yes
>
> It ain't me, it ain't me, I ain't no millionaire's son, no
>
> It ain't me, it ain't me; I ain't no fortunate one, no

Answer (score 1):

I can think of *enriched* or *over-privileged*, but neither is a perfect fit.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt for *God's pet*— quite tongue-in-cheek, but like *teacher's pet*.

Comment: Is this an idiom or something you made up yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer the word *fortuitous*.

Comment: Fortuitous is not synonymous with fortunate. It means "happened by chance".

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen anyone else suggest "endowed". To be endowed is to be granted gifts.

"Every person is endowed with God-given abilities, and we must cultivate every ounce of talent we have in order to maintain our pinnacle position in the world." Benjamin Carson.

"He was endowed with good looks, charm, and a rich family".

Answer (score -1):

for a while i was thinking: 'one who is, shall we say,  among the entitled?'

but

'among the privileged' might be a better, and perhaps less snarky fit.

thinking [Antonio Gramsci](http://www.studyplace.org/wiki/Talk:Antonio_Gramsci_(1891-1937)).  thinking [Peggy McIntosh](http://www.colorlines.com/articles/peggy-mcintosh-sets-record-straight-white-privilege)'s 1988 essay, "White Privilege: Unpacking the Invisible Knapsack." but that's all a little more small 'p' political than finding a generic word.  still.  it's all wrapped up together.

OED says:

> entitlement, n.
>
> The belief that one is inherently deserving of privileges or special treatment. Freq. in  sense of entitlement.

and

> privileged
>
> 2.a.
> Of a person, or class of people: having or enjoying certain privileges, rights, or advantages; treated with special favour.
>
> privilege
>
> 3.b.
> A special advantage, benefit, or favour (bestowed by God, providence, chance, etc.); an exceptionally rare and fortunate opportunity; the honour or good fortune of something or to do something.

Comment: Hello, rn tmssn, and welcome to English Language & Usage. Your suggestion of _entitled_ is apt, and it's one that no one else has previously suggested. At this site, however, much stress is laid on presenting answers that are supported by authoritative reference works. In this instance, you could strengthen your answer considerably by supplying a dictionary definition of the noun _entitled_ that shows why it is a good fit in answer to the poster's question. Thanks!